# will vacuumlo find orphaned objects

Tags: postgresql-9.1, datatypes, alter-table, blob, vacuum

A Table (mytable) is having 2 columns

```
id_       | loid_
(integer) | (oid)
```

Values are

```
id_    | loid_
1      | 15001
2      | 15002
```

Value in loid_ column refers the oid from pg_largeobject. And if I am running vacuumlo it wont show these two ids as orphaned object. If I removed these two entries from mytable and running vacuumlo, now these two ids being considered by vacuumlo as orphaned objects.

If I change the loid_ columns data type as integer by using below query,

```
alter table mytable alter column loid_ type integer; --works fine here
```

Update:

I have done some testing, seems its considering as orphaned object by vacuumlo.

it will impact anything? can I execute alter command?

Comment: Everything is OK, isn't it? I mean the data base did what was expectable from it, didn't it?

Comment: yeah, it worked without causing any issue in my scenario.